# Ruby/Rails best way to pass model specific attributes for grouping purposes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to add some client-side list grouping functionality into my Rails app. It's basically a user list view where the user model would have different groupable attributes, like e-mail, name, title, etc... I was thinking of having the model include a `def groupable` that would return a hash containing all that model instance's groupable values. The keys would be fixed, known strings, that could be localized from the view. e.g. `user.name= "Group by name"`, `user.title= "Group by title"`, etc...

The controller would retrieve the user models in `def index` like normal, but it would also call `groupable` on each one and build an object that the view can use to generate a JavaScript variable/hash/JSON which I could use from JavaScript/jQuery to to the grouping on the client-side. I can also pre-group the list in the view, like by default all users are grouped by name alphanumeric.

The idea is to allow for client-side groupings that don't require a page refresh.

I expect the usual method of using a partial and some AJAX could do the trick, but I was hoping the user list wouldn't have to be reloaded each time the grouping was changed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to a dynamic, pure JavaScript + jQuery list grouping implementation without the need for Rails served grouping content to the view. It's much more flexible this way and I kind of consider JS a requirement for more advanced features like grouping and other features, so with JS turned off, the listing would work fine, with it on you get grouping, highlighting, client-side instant search, etc...